# EchoDot is unable to request my skill tough it works in web interface

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I just tried to develop a skill for Alexa in C#. It just consits out of a simple intent with a slot for a name and says something like "Hi {name}" as response.

I created an AWS Lambda project in visual studio, referenced [alexa skills for .Net core by Tim Heuer](https://github.com/timheuer/alexa-skills-dotnet) and implemented the intent:

```
var name = intentRequest.Intent.Slots["name"].Value;
var speech = new Alexa.NET.Response.SsmlOutputSpeech {Ssml = $"Hallo {name}. Schön dich zu sehen."};

response = ResponseBuilder.Tell(speech);
response.Response.ShouldEndSession = true;
```

I published it into my AWS Lambdas via Visual Studio AWS Toolkit, added Alexa as a trigger and created the Alexa skill and referenced it to the lambdas arn.

I enabled the skill for my own echo dot device, I also can see it exists in my app. If I now ask the echo dot to launch the skill I just get an error saying "An error occurred during the response of the requested skill" (translated from German). But if I test the skill in the Alexa developer website on Amazon it all works fine. Same if I test it in visual studio itself.

Skills in general work on my echo dot (also the node js trivia game example). What might cause this problem? Is this an error in my lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that the SsmlOutputSpeech was the problem. Seems like you have to fill in the string in Ssml syntax, even it wasn´t done like this in the related GitHub repository. I just moved to PlainTextOutputSpeech as this is enough for my cases.